# jQuery.proxy() usage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was reading the api about [`jQuery.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/). It looks promising but I was wondering in what situation is this best use. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/4986562 for a great explanation

Answer (score 143, accepted):

When you want a function that has the `this` value bound to a specific object. For example, in callbacks such as event handlers, AJAX callbacks, timeouts, intervals, custom objects, etc.

This is just a manufactured example of a situation where it might be useful. Assuming there is a `Person` object which has a property name. It is also linked to a text input element, and whenever the input value changes, the name in this person object gets updated too.

```
function Person(el) {
    this.name = '';

    $(el).change(function(event) {
        // Want to update this.name of the Person object,
        // but can't because this here refers to the element
        // that triggered the change event.
    });
}
```

One solution that we often use is to store the this context in a variable and use that inside the callback function such as:

```
function Person(el) {
    this.name = '';

    var self = this; // store reference to this

    $(el).change(function(event) {
        self.name = this.value; // captures self in a closure
    });
}
```

Alternatively, we could have used `jQuery.proxy` here so the reference to `this` refers to the object of Person instead of the element that triggered the event.

```
function Person(el) {
    this.name = '';

    $(el).change(jQuery.proxy(function(event) {
        this.name = event.target.value;
    }, this));
}
```

Note that this feature has been standardized into ECMAScript 5 which now includes the [`bind`](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/) method borrowed from [prototypejs](/questions/tagged/prototypejs) and is already available on some browsers.

```
function Person(el) {
    this.name = '';

    $(el).change(function(event) {
        this.name = event.target.value;
    }.bind(this)); // we're binding the function to the object of person
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning that this has found its way into ECMAscript.

Comment: Is is *better* (faster, more efficient) to use a regular closure, or to use $.proxy?

Comment: @AnsonMacKeracher it is better and faster not to use a closure at all but a proxied static function. These answers don't show that proxy can be used with static functions where as the `self = this` hack can only be used if you create the function inline

Comment: Just to go one step further, in ECMAScript 6 (ES6) Arrow Functions are the way to go (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

`
function Person(el) {
    this.name = '';

    $(el).change((event) => {
        this.name = event.target.value;
    });
}
`

Answer (score 17):

It's just a shorthand method of setting the context for a closure, for example:

```
$(".myClass").click(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert(this); //window
  }, 1000);
});
```

However often we want `this` to remain the same as the method we were in, which `$.proxy()` is used for, like this:

```
$("button").click(function() {
  setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
    alert(this); //button
  }, this), 1000);
});​
```

It's usually used for delayed calls, or anywhere you don't want to do a longhand method of declaring a closure.  The string method of pointing the context to an object...well I haven't come across a practical use in every day code yet, but I'm sure there are applications, just depends what your object/event structure is.

Answer (score 14):

For example if you want to create callbacks. Instead of:

```
var that = this;

$('button').click(function() {
    that.someMethod();
});
```

you can do:

```
$('button').click($.proxy(this.someMethod, this));
```

Or if you create a plugin that accepts callbacks and you have to set a specific context for the callback.