# Understanding $.proxy() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

From [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/) I understand that `.proxy()` would change the scope of the function passed as an argument. Could someone please explain me this better? Why should we do this?

Comment: According to the documentation, "This method is most useful for attaching event handlers to an element where the context is pointing back to a different object. Additionally, jQuery makes sure that even if you bind the function returned from jQuery.proxy() it will still unbind the correct function, if passed the original". Is there anything particular about that phrasing you find lacking?

Comment: This is unclear here Additionally, jQuery makes sure that even if you bind the function returned from jQuery.proxy() it will still unbind the correct function, if passed the original".What's meant by original?

Comment: The original is that for which a proxy was created. But since you don't fully grasp this stuff, are you sure you need to use it?

Comment: Here's a great video tutorial by nettuts showing how $.proxy works.
[http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-learning-jquery-1-4s-proxy/](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-learning-jquery-1-4s-proxy/)

Comment: @bzlm , I was reading jquery documentation when i came up at this method.

Comment: for more advanced, i would recommend this question too: [javascript - What is the difference between $.proxy() and bind()? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501231/what-is-the-difference-between-proxy-and-bind)

Comment: [This video](https://frontendmasters.com/courses/javascript-jquery-dom/exercise-11-implementing-proxy/) in FrontendMasters helped me a lot to release it since the teacher explains what is happening in the memory with the references to the functions/objects in plain js

Answer (score 389, accepted):

What it ultimately does is it ensures that the value of `this` in a function will be the value you desire.

A common example is in a `setTimeout` that takes place inside a `click` handler.

Take this:

```
$('#myElement').click(function() {
        // In this function, "this" is our DOM element.
    $(this).addClass('aNewClass');
});
```

The intention is simple enough. When `myElement` is clicked, it should get the class `aNewClass`. Inside the handler `this` represents the element that was clicked.

But what if we wanted a short delay before adding the class? We might use a `setTimeout` to accomplish it, but the trouble is that whatever function we give to `setTimeout`, the value of `this` inside that function will be `window` instead of our element.

```
$('#myElement').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
          // Problem! In this function "this" is not our element!
        $(this).addClass('aNewClass');
    }, 1000);
});
```

So what we can do instead, is to call `$.proxy()`, sending it the function and the value we want to assign to `this`, and it will return a function that will retain that value.

```
$('#myElement').click(function() {
   // ------------------v--------give $.proxy our function,
    setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
        $(this).addClass('aNewClass');  // Now "this" is again our element
    }, this), 1000);
   // ---^--------------and tell it that we want our DOM element to be the
   //                      value of "this" in the function
});
```

So after we gave `$.proxy()` the function, and the value we want for `this`, it returned a function that will ensure that `this` is properly set.

How does it do it? It just returns an anonymous function that *calls* our function using the `.apply()` method, which lets it explicitly set the value of `this`.

A simplified look at the function that is returned may look like:

```
function() {
    // v--------func is the function we gave to $.proxy
    func.apply( ctx );
    // ----------^------ ctx is the value we wanted for "this" (our DOM element)
}
```

So this anonymous function is given to `setTimeout`, and all it does is execute our original function with the proper `this` context.

Comment: What's the value of using `$.proxy(function () {...}, this)` rather than `(function() {...}).call(this)`? Is there a difference?

Comment: @JustinMorgan: with `.call` you are calling the function immediately. With `$.proxy`, it is like `Function.prototype.bind` where it returns a new function. That new function has the `this` value permanently bound, so that when it is passed to `setTimeout`, and `setTimeout` calls the function later, it will still have the correct `this` value.

Comment: What's the advantage, if any, of this technique over something like this?

    $('#myElement').click(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            el.addClass('aNewClass');
        }, 1000);
    });

Comment: You don't need to use jQuery for this. You can achieve it by using plain JS, too:                                $('#myElement').click(function() {

    setTimeout((function (this) {
  return function () {
   this.className = this.className + " aNewClass";   
  }
 })(this)), 1000);
});

Comment: You do not have to use $.proxy method for this example .Instead you can simply re -write it like this 
$('#myElement').click(function() {
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
          // new context through a variable declared in scope of handler method
        $(that).addClass('aNewClass');
    }, 1000);
});

Comment: hey can you just clear my doubt related to `$.proxy()` I posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946312/why-the-handler-attached-using-proxy-is-not-getting-detached-after-first-c)

Comment: An anonymous user with 112k rep, scary-good JavaScript/jQuery knowledge, and hasn't been seen since October 2011... John Resig perhaps?

Comment: I like non-passive aggressive answers like this one :)  Now I get it!

Comment: @cantera you mean a dual identity apart from [John Resig](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6524/john-resig)? :)

Comment: This what I call an explanation!

Answer (score 53):

Without going into greater detail (which would be necessary because this is about **Context** in ECMAScript, the **this context variable** etc.)

There are three different types of "Contexts" in ECMA-/Javascript:

- The global context
- Function context
- eval context

Every code is executed in its **execution context**. There is **one** global context and there can be many instances of function (and eval) contexts. Now the interesting part:

Every call of a function enters the function execution context. An execution context of a function looks like:

**The Activation Object**
**Scope Chain**
**this value**

So the **this** value is a special object which is related with the execution context. There are two functions in ECMA-/Javascript which may change the **this** value in a function execution context:

```
.call()
.apply()
```

If we have a function `foobar()` we can change the **this** value by calling:

```
foobar.call({test: 5});
```

Now we could access in `foobar` the object we passed in:

```
function foobar() { 
    this.test // === 5
}
```

This is exactly what `jQuery.proxy()` does. It takes a `function` and `context` (which is nothing else than an object) and links the function by invoking `.call()` or `.apply()` and returns that new function.

Comment: Excellent explanation, simpler/better than the official jQuery docs for the function

Answer (score 4):

I have written this function:

```
function my_proxy (func,obj)
{
    if (typeof(func)!="function")
        return;

    // If obj is empty or another set another object 
    if (!obj) obj=this;

    return function () { return func.apply(obj,arguments); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The same goal can be achieved using a "Immediately-Invoked Function Expression, short: IIFE"  <strike>self executing function</strike>:

```js
    $('#myElement').click(function() {  
      (function(el){
         setTimeout(function() {
              // Problem! In this function "this" is not our element!
            el.addClass('colorme');
        }, 1000);
      })($(this)); // self executing function   
    });
```

```css
.colorme{
  color:red;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

  <div id="myElement">Click me</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's usually called an "Immediately-Invoked Function Expression"  (IIFE) rather than a "self executing function", see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression.