# jQuery Proxy with Anonymous function

Tags: jquery, proxy

I was wondering how to use the `$.proxy` with an anonymous function

```
(function hours() {
   //some stuff here
})();
```

And then something like

```
($.proxy(function hours() {
//some stuff here
},this)();
```

But that doesnt work ? Any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.proxy` is just going to maintain the executing context, it was intended to close over `this`. A good explanation of `proxy` overall can be found here: [Understanding $.proxy() in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4986329/1026459)

The correct usage for your demo would be

```
var prox = $.proxy(function hours() {
 //some stuff here
},this);
```

And then you can use `prox()` later on and it will share the `this` scope you closed over. If `this` was the window, then it really didn't accomplish much. As for the anonymous function, it doesn't really matter if it is named or not.

I relocated the name above just to show that you are essentially storing a function. When `prox()` is used from this example, it essentially uses `hours.apply(this-closed-scope)`.