# context in function in object method

Tags: javascript, function, callback, this

There is piece of code:

```
var object = {
    findById: function(idNumber) {
        var data = this.childNodes;
        var returnItems = {};

        function callback(node) {
            if (parseInt(node.id) === idNumber)
                returnItems = node;
        };

        function iterator(node, callback) {
            callback(node);
            var nodes = node.childNodes;
            if (nodes === undefined) {
                return;
            };
            for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                var iterNode = nodes[i];
                iterator(iterNode, callback);
            };
        };

        function bind(func, context) {
            return function() { // (*)
                return func.apply(context, arguments);
            };
        };

        for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            iterator(data[i], callback);
        };

        return returnItems;
    },
}
```

How to import context in to iterator and callback function?
if I put console.log(this) into function iterator() - this will be 'window', but not my object.
Also it shouldn't be this.callback this.iterator etc. 
As I understand it should be like call/apply or bind.
How do it?

Comment: I think $.proxy is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986329/understanding-proxy-in-jquery

Comment: [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: @Failwyn there's no mention made in this question of jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Copy a reference to this inside the `findById` function.

   ```
   var object = {
     findById: function(idNumber) {
       var data = this.childNodes;
       var returnItems = {};

       // assign this to a variable
       // you can use inside the nested functions
       var that = this;


       function callback(node) {
         if (parseInt(node.id) === idNumber)
           returnItems = node;
       };

       function iterator(node, callback) {
         callback(node);
         var nodes = node.childNodes;
         if (nodes === undefined) {
           return;
         };
         for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
           var iterNode = nodes[i];
           iterator(iterNode, callback);
         };
       };

       function bind(func, context) {
         return function() { // (*)
           return func.apply(context, arguments);
         };
       };


       for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
         iterator(data[i], callback);
       };

       return returnItems;
     }
   };
   ```
2. Use [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

   ```
   for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     iterator.call(this, data[i], callback);
   };
   ```

Answer (score 0):

wherever you use functions do it this way:

```
functionToCall.apply(this,params); //this or the context you want to have inside
```

Sample:

```
function callable() {
   console.log(this);
}
callable(); //logs window
callable.apply({}); //logs {}
```

Comment: It is hard to understand...how it will be work at my code?
function callback.apply(this,node) {
    if (parseInt(node.id) === idNumber)
    returnItems = node;
};??

Comment: no no no, its not on the definition. its when you call the function. Instead of calling callback(node) you call it: callback.apply(this,node)