# $(this) in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, raty

I'm having a problem with using `this` in js. I have a function that uses `this` like this:

```javascript
var refreshRequesterStar = function() {
    $(".rating").raty({
        score: function() { return $(this).attr('data-rating'); },
        readOnly: function() { return $(this).attr('data-readonly'); },
        halfShow: true
    });
};
```

The rating div is as follow:

```html
<div class="rating" data-readonly="false" data-rating="3.0" style="cursor: default; width: 100px;" title="not rated yet">
<div class="rating" data-readonly="false" data-rating="0.0" style="cursor: default; width: 100px;" title="not rated yet">
```

This is called by this function:

```javascript
$("body").ajaxComplete(function(){
      refreshRequesterStar();
      $(".time_to_expire").each(function(){
            setCountDown(this);
      })
      $('select').chosen();
});
```

I was able to set the score value but I cannot set the readOnly value. When I debugged using firebug, I found that the first this pointed to the div but the second this pointed to window. Where I have been wrong? Note: I don't know much about JavaScript.

More info: I was using raty http://www.wbotelhos.com/raty with rails.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript "this" referce to wrong object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173385/javascript-this-referce-to-wrong-object) and [javascript 'this' scope in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039487/javascript-this-scope-in-jquery).

Comment: btw, this is not pure javascript. From the looks and the use of `$`, i would say it's jQuery. Nevertheless, this and scope are a tricky thing in JS, especially for programmer with a more traditional background

Comment: It's actually jQuery. I'm sorry that I haven't add the jquery tag. Since it's jquery,I don't think this question is a duplicate.

Comment: You have data-readOnly instead of data-readonly in here: return $(this).attr('data-readOnly'); and the attribute is data-readonly. Check it out!

Comment: not offering this as an answer because I'm not sure and my jQuery is rusty...but shouldn't `.attr('data-readOnly')` match `data-readonly="false"` (different cased `o`) ?

Comment: Sorry. It's my typo. In the source code, they are both readonly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation and examples indicate that the parameter `score` and `readOnly` are supposed to be numeric and boolean, not callback functions. You might want to re-write your code this:

```javascript
$(".rating").each(function() {
    // inside the function, this refers to the .rating element being iterated
    $(this).raty({
        score:    parseFloat($(this).attr('data-rating')), // see note #1
        readOnly: $(this).attr('data-readonly') == "true", // see note #2
        halfShow: true
    });
});
```

1. `.attr()` returns a string; [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) function is used to convert a string e.g. `"2.5"` into the number `2.5`
2. `== "true"` returns boolean true if the attribute value is equal to `"true"`; returns false in all other cases

Ref:

- [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)
- [jQuery.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: not a big fan of the unary operator suggestion given here and will also violate jslint validation.. Rather cast it like this: `Number($(this).attr('data-rating');`