# Marionette js - how does coffeescript's fat arrow translate to Javascript in this custom region I'm building?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, jquery-ui-dialog, marionette, region

At 22:30 of this video tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBVYDVy3QNI, the author does something in coffeescript that I'm unable to translate to Javascript.  He maintains the context of a custom region from within an inner callback using a fat arrow.  As such, he is able to call close on the region from within a dialog close callback?  How do I do that in Javascript?

Here is my custom region attempt but it fails on the call to this.closeDialog() because "this" refers to the dialog and not the region:

```
    var DialogRegion = Backbone.Marionette.Region.extend({

        onShow: function (view) {
            this.$el.dialog({
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                draggable: false,
                width: "600px",
                close: function (e, ui) {
                        this.closeDialog()//This doesn't work.  Wrong context.  Need outer DialogRegion context?                
                }
            })
        },        

        closeDialog: function () {
            this.close();
            this.$el.dialog("destroy");
        }

    });
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can assume a reasonably modern JavaScript then you can use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value [...]

That would look like this:

```
close: function (e, ui) {
    this.closeDialog();
}.bind(this)
```

You're using Marionette so you're using Backbone and that implies that Underscore is available. That means that you could use [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) if you don't want to use the native `bind`:

```
close: _(function (e, ui) {
    this.closeDialog();
}).bind(this)
```

You're using jQuery-UI so you should have [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) available too. `$.proxy` serves the same purpose as `_.bind` and you'd use it thusly:

```
close: $.proxy(function(e, ui) {
    this.closeDialog();
}, this)
```

The "classic" option is the one that [elclanrs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/670396/elclanrs) mentions in the comments:

```
onShow: function (view) {
    var _this = this;
    this.$el.dialog({
        //...
        close: function (e, ui) {
            _this.closeDialog()
        }
    });
}
```

All four of those will be functionally equivalent to the `close: (e, ui) => ...` you saw in the CoffeeScript video.

Comment: And what about `$.proxy`? Any thoughts on that one with regard to the above mentioned methods? Edit: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349380/jquery-proxy-usage. So better use the native or underscore `bind`.

Comment: @WilbertvandeRidder: Right, I tend to forget about `$.proxy` since I usually have Underscore available. You could use `$.proxy` too, the `var _this = this` approach seems to be more common in the jQuery world though.

Comment: Excellent.  Lots of options.  Thanks much.  First and last work.  I'll verify the other two as well when I get a chance here.  Based on what I'm reading at the links you provided, they should work.