# jquery.ajax request through proxy server

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova, proxy

I'm developping an android app using phonegap. The app can upload data to a distant server which host a web app. The ajax call is working, but I want to take care of people whom don't have direct access to the server, and need to add proxy settings.

I'm not sure where to add these settings in my code.. Is this going in the URL? Or do you have to just put the proxy settings into the android system to make all the applications call passing through your proxy? Or is it something else? ^^

Thanks for the help,
Laurent.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349380/jquery-proxy-usage

Comment: it's not what I'm asking ;D I've trouble finding the answer because of this proxy method, & the proxy pattern !