# Change instance property from prototype method

Tags: javascript, class, oop, methods, prototype

I'm trying to build a reusable `Database` class with prototypical methods to add items to the class's `list` array property:

```
    var Database = function() {
        this.list = [];
    }

    Database.prototype = {
        getBooks: function () {
            $.get("//some.url/books")
            .success(function(res) {
                _.each(res,function(book) {
                    this.list.push({
                        name: book.name,
                        url: book.url,
                        type: "book"
                    })
                })
            });
        }
    }
```

However, currently I get a warning saying that I cannot push to undefined property `list`, and I can only assume that I'm not actually `.push`ing to any `Database` class instance property, but rather to the prototype property.

So, the question restated: **How do you use a prototype method to change an instance's properties?**

Comment: I realise this is slightly duplicative as an answer, but I couldn't wrap my head around the fairly long/abstract answers already provided on StackOverflow/elsewhere. The answer accepted is simple and to the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store reference to `this` in variable, like this

```
 Database.prototype = {
        getBooks: function () {
           var _this = this;
            $.get("//some.url/books")
            .success(function(res) {
                _.each(res,function(book) {
                    _this.list.push({
                        name: book.name,
                        url: book.url,
                        type: "book"
                    })
                })
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why does `this` work for the `getBooks` scope, but not further into the nested functions? Is this because `this` is then in the reference to the success/_.each callbacks?

Comment: @J.B. yes because in _.each this refers to another scope, not on Database.prototype

Comment: In hindsight this seems so obvious. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

What "this" refers, depends on the situation. Check mdn for more detailed info: [MDN this operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

And this thread can help you understand clearly how to pass "this" to another scope: [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349380/jquery-proxy-usage)